# Convert HashMap values into BinaryHeap

Tags: rust

I am talking about `std::collections::hash_map::Values` struct, which you get from calling `.values()` method on a`HashMap`. This struct really confuses me, how can I access its values without iterating over them? I want to turn those values into a `BinaryHeap` like so:

```
let heap = BinaryHeap::from(map.values());
```

I read the documentation and it seems this struct does not really have a simple way of accessing its elements

Comment: Do you really mean "How can I convert an iterator into a vector"?

Comment: @tadman, I tried following: `let v: Vec<i32> = map.values().into_iter().collect();` but it did not work, gave me an error that `std::vec::Vec<i32>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&{integer}`

Comment: If you're converting types in the middle you need to do another map operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Values`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.Values.html) struct is defined as

> An iterator over the values of a HashMap.

However, there is an easy way to convert the values into a `BinaryHeap`. Since it implements [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html), you can do

```rust
let heap: BinaryHeap<_> = map.values().collect();
```

The code above will create a `BinaryHeap` of references. If you want the heap to own the values, you can either move the values out of the map like this:

```rust
let heap: BinaryHeap<_> = map.drain().map(|(_key, value)| value).collect();
```

or clone the values:

```rust
let heap: BinaryHeap<_> = map.values().cloned().collect();
```

Note that if your value type is `Copy` (like `i32`), you can call `.copied()` instead of `.cloned()`. This does not speed up the process, but it is more accurate and good practice.

Comment: I tried first version and it worked fine. Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that you can use `.copied()` instead of `.cloned()` to assert that the clone is "cheap" (amounting to a bitwise copy of the data).

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks, I added a mention at the end